# JMeter - Datetime value is different when selecting from postgresql DB

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, jmeter

In my JMeter test case, I'm selecting a timestamp with timezone field from a postgresql DB.

The thing is, when I run the test case on a fresh instance of JMeter for the first time, the value is converted to my local datetime.

Value in DB: `2019-10-23 06:20:54.086605+00`

Value when using select: `2019-10-23 11:50:54.086605`

But often when I run the test case again on the same JMeter instance, it is not converted.

Value in DB: `2019-10-23 06:42:15.77647+00`

Value when using select: `2019-10-23 06:42:15.77647`

Restarting JMeter will again result in the 1st behavior. I'm not able to exactly pinpoint how and when this switch in behavior happens. It happens now and then, but restarting JMeter will always reset to the 1st behavior.

I have tried setting the timezone value in postgres.conf file as well as user.timezone value in system.properties in JMeter /bin directory to `UTC`, to no avail.

I'm using `SELECT *` to select all columns from the table and storing them in variables using the Variable names field in JDBC Request.

Comment: What is the type of the column?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel It's timestamp with time zone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that PostgreSQL [`timestamp with time zone`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html) is being [mapped](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html) to [java.sql.Timestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) which doesn't contain timezone information.

The only workaround I can think of is converting the aforementioned Timestamp providing the [TimeZone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) as the parameter like:

1. In the JDBC Request sampler define `Result Variable Name`

   [image]
2. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request and use the below Groovy code to convert the Timestamp into the TimeZone of your choice:

   ```
   vars.getObject("resultSet").get(0).get("bar").format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ', TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC'))
   ```

   [image]

More information: [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter/)

Comment: Thanks, that's a good solution. But I did a workaround by selecting the timestamps in another JDBC Request like so: `SELECT datetime AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'`, and it worked.